# what's the meaning of this formula "cutoff frequency / (b/8)"

Tags: hardware

I am not sure whether my question is suit for this place. I am a newbie in computer networks. And I choose Andrew S. Tanenbaum's Computer Networks for my textbook. In the second chapter:

> Given a bit rate of b bits/sec, the time required to send the 8 bits in our example
>   1 bit at a time is 8/b sec, so the frequency of the first harmonic of this signal
>   is b /8 Hz. An ordinary telephone line, often called a voice-grade line, has an
>   artificially introduced cutoff frequency just above 3000 Hz. The presence of this
>   restriction means that the number of the highest harmonic passed through is
>   roughly 3000/(b/8), or 24,000/b (the cutoff is not sharp).

Here I can't see why the number of the highest harmonic passed through is roughly 3000/(b/8). I think b/8 is the number of harmonics transmit in one second. so if the cutoff frequency is 3000 Hz. then we must transmit about 3000 harmonics to rebuilt the signal. so I think 3000 / (b/8) is the time of transmit a signal. Please help me... thanks very much.

Comment: This material seems a bit dated, but that's besides the question. One thing that might be confusing here is that *harmonic number* doesn't seem to be clearly defined. This is not about "transmitting harmonics", it's bits that are being transmitted, but the signaling is actually analog, so there are harmonic frequencies generated that might be necessary for the signal. Harmonic frequencies are multiples of the base frequency, and each different multiple has a harmonic number. Also I think this might be off-topic here.

Comment: Digital signals don't have a "harmonic". The PSTN is limited by the digital encoding (8000 8bit samples per second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward to me, and I am not sure where your confusion is coming from at this point. Perhaps it's the math and if we made the example a bit more concrete you might pick up on this?

Let's set ***b*** to 80, or 80 bit/sec. This means that the time it takes to send 8 bits one bit at a time is 1/10 second (8/***b*** sec). Or to put this into terms of frequency, this harmonic requires 10 Hz (***b***/8 Hz).

Now we introduce this harmonic onto our medium with a restriction of 3000 Hz (ordinary telephone line) and we want to find the highest number of this harmonic we can pass on this medium. We have already found that the first harmonic for this example requires 10 Hz, so the highest number of harmonics we can pass on this medium is 300 (3000 Hz/10 Hz). Or to follow the math as it is laid out in the book, 3000/(80/8) or 24,000/80, which both give us the same result.

To change it up, let's now change ***b*** to 10 bps. This gives us a first harmonic of 1.25 Hz, and the highest harmonic on the medium of 2400.

Does that help?